# Faster vectorization of np.unique to get the item count in a matrix of multidimensional indices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I'm interested in counting the number of times an index appears in a matrix of shape `(size, 3)`, where `size` is a big number. For illustration purposes, in a loop this looks like:

```
max_ = 30
size = 300000
idx_matrix = np.random.randint(0, max_, (size, 3))
result = np.zeros((max_, max_, max_), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(idx_matrix)): 
    result[tuple(idx_matrix[i, :])] += 1 
result = result / np.sum(result) # Normalization
```

I made the following vectorized implementation using `np.unique` with `return_counts=True`, but it's not fast enough for my purposes since I am going to be doing this operation hundreds of times.

```
import numpy as np

def foo():
    max_ = 30
    size = 300000
    idx_matrix = np.random.randint(0, max_, (size, 3))
    result = np.zeros((max_, max_, max_), dtype=int)

    unique, counts = np.unique(idx_matrix, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    result[unique[:, 0], unique[:, 1], unique[:, 2]] = counts
    return result / np.sum(result)

>>> %timeit foo()
    464 ms ± 22.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

How could I improve this code further so that it takes considerably less time than half a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method of the [`numpy.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html). In the following, I've removed the generation of `idx_matrix` from `foo()`, so you can verify that `foo()` and `foo2()` return the same result, and so the timing does not include the generation of `idx_matrix`.

```
def foo(idx_matrix, max_):
    result = np.zeros((max_, max_, max_), dtype=int)
    unique, counts = np.unique(idx_matrix, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    result[unique[:, 0], unique[:, 1], unique[:, 2]] = counts
    return result / len(idx_matrix)


def foo2(idx_matrix, max_):
    result = np.zeros((max_, max_, max_), dtype=int)
    np.add.at(result, tuple(idx_matrix.T), 1)
    return result / len(idx_matrix)


max_ = 30
size = 300000
idx_matrix = np.random.randint(0, max_, (size, 3))
```

Here are the timings for `foo(idx_matrix, max_)` and `foo2(idx_matrix, max_)`:

```
In [64]: %timeit foo(idx_matrix, max_)
349 ms ± 5.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [65]: %timeit foo2(idx_matrix, max_)
26.3 ms ± 456 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `np.bincount` is often suggested as a faster alternative to `add.at`.